# take json array value and put its in seprate div by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have JSON array like this

i want access each JSON array and put its values in specific div

i don't know how is it in jQuery

```
[{
  "note_id": 1,
  "developer_id": 7,
  "note": "in it note ",
  "created_at": "2017-08-25 00:00:00"
}, {
  "note_id": 2,
  "developer_id": 7,
  "note": "it is second note",
  "created_at": "2017-08-25 00:00:00"
}]
```

i parse that with JSON.parse() and write this

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   console.log(data.name);
}
```

but say undefined.

Comment: Try  console.log(data[i].note);

Comment: or using modern Array.prototype.forEach:
```data.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
});```

Comment: With in your JSON array. I am not able to see `name`

Comment: you don't need `JSON.parse` and you don't have `name` property

Comment: sorry my mean was note i dont have name key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a JSON, you need to use `JSON.parse()`. You can use `console.log(data[i])` and to get inner values, you should use `console.log(data[i].note_id)`. And yes, there is not as `name` in your JSON.

```js
var data = [{
  "note_id": 1,
  "developer_id": 7,
  "note": "in it note ",
  "created_at": "2017-08-25 00:00:00"
}, {
  "note_id": 2,
  "developer_id": 7,
  "note": "it is second note",
  "created_at": "2017-08-25 00:00:00"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  $("#developer_note").append("<div>"+data[i].note+"</div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='developer_note'></div>
```

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Comment: i want have each arrays data in a diffrent div ?
how should it be ?

Comment: for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        $("#developer_note").html("<div>"+data[i].note+"</div>");
    }

somthing like this create one div with same note  @Milan

Comment: @moh - Updated the answer.

Comment: one more question this loop create 2 seprate div for use  can we do somthing that this element place in uniqe div with unique id ??? somthing like 
<div>
<div class="loop">
<div class=""loop>
</div>

<div>
<div class="another loop"></div>
<div class="another loop"></div>
</div>



  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        $("#developer_note").append("<div>"+data[i].note+"</div>");
        $("#developer_note").append("<div>"+data[i].created_at+"</div>");
    }

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead and do that way too. Assign `id` to each div so that they are unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152817/discussion-between-moh-and-milan-chheda).